# vb.net check if function don't return anything

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net function is which I am doing some thing which is returning a gridview to send it in email.Problem is that when I call the function in email then email is sent even there is nothing returned by function. I don't to send blank email at all. I want to when function return nothing then it shouldn't send email. Here is My function

```
Public Function emaildata(ByVal grdv As GridView, ByVal chk As String, ByVal celpos As Integer) As GridView
        Dim comm As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        Dim bpv As String = ""
        Dim gv As New GridView
        For Each gvrow As GridViewRow In grdv.Rows
            Try
                Dim rdobtn As RadioButtonList = CType(gvrow.FindControl(chk), RadioButtonList)
                If rdobtn.SelectedValue.Equals("5") Or rdobtn.SelectedValue.Equals("1") Or rdobtn.SelectedValue.Equals("6") Or rdobtn.SelectedValue.Equals("4") Or rdobtn.SelectedValue.Equals("2") Then
                    If bpv <> "" Then
                        bpv += ","
                    End If
                    bpv += gvrow.Cells(celpos).Text
                    comm.CommandText = "SELECT row_number() over(order by rownum) Sr, to_char(chq_num) Cheque#,to_char(bpv_amt,'9,999,999,999') Amount,vch_nar Narration,bnf_nam PartyName,acc_des Bank from  CHECK_DATA where bpv_num in(" & bpv.ToString() & ") and BPV_DTE=to_date('" & TreeView2.SelectedValue & "') union all SELECT null,'Total :',to_char(sum(bpv_amt),'9,999,999,999') Amount,null,null,null from  CHECK_DATA where bpv_num in(" & bpv.ToString() & ") and BPV_DTE=to_date('" & TreeView2.SelectedValue & "')"
                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    comm.Connection = con
                    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(comm)
                    Dim ds As New DataSet
                    da.Fill(ds)
                    gv.DataSource = ds
                    gv.DataBind()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write("There is Problem In Cheque Approval System Please Contact With IT")
            End Try
        Next
        Return gv
    End Function
```

And I Call this in email function as a subject like this

```
email("malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk", "[Cheque Approval] GM Finance Reviewed (" & TreeView2.SelectedValue & ")" & subsmcnt(GridView5, "chkStatusGM", 4), gridhtm(emaildata(GridView5, "chkStatusGM", 4)))
```

How can I do this that if `emaildata(GridView5, "chkStatusGM", 4)` returning nothing email shouldn't be sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to check if the `GridView` contains `GridViewRows` with the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection.count.aspx) property:

```
Dim grdEmail = emaildata(GridView5, "chkStatusGM", 4)
If grdEmail.Rows.Count > 0
    email("malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk", 
          "[Cheque Approval] GM Finance Reviewed (" & TreeView2.SelectedValue & ")" & subsmcnt(GridView5, "chkStatusGM", 4), 
          gridhtm(grdEmail))
End If
```